# How to replace NULL values with maximum value in column in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table tab1, I want to replace NULL values in a column with the maximum values in column.

| id | name | email |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sta | sta@example.com |
| NULL | Danny | dany@example.com |
| 3 | Elle | elle@example.com |

I want the output like this

| id | name | email |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sta | sta@example.com |
| 3 | Danny | dany@example.com |
| 3 | Elle | elle@example.com |

Answer (score 1):

We use `coalesce` to replace `nulls` and `max() over()` to choose max value in column.

```
select  coalesce(ID, max(id) over()) as id
       ,name
       ,email
from    t
```

| ID | NAME | EMAIL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sta | sta@example.com |
| 3 | Danny | dany@example.com |
| 3 | Elle | elle@example.com |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/EXl0SII3)